# Can I create Azure File Share using Ansible?

Tags: azure, ansible

Is it possible to create an azure storage file share using Ansible ?
There is an Ansible module to create Azure Storage Account, so I am good there.
I dont see anything for File Share.
There is something called `azure_rm_resource` but I have not been able to get it to work with it.
Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: You easily could. Just paste the command in Ansible to create a storage file share:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share?tabs=azure-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my answer as it will help someone in the community:

The latest commit contains this enhancement !

https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/pull/603/commits/83a6600417faccf56752a8ae5b1e52a0bac37dfb

Copying the example from the link above :

```
- name: Create storage share
  azure_rm_storageshare:
    name: testShare
    resource_group: myResourceGroup
    account_name: testStorageAccount
    state: present
    access_tier: Cool
    quota: 2048
    metadata:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not yet in the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/index.html#plugins-in-azure-azcollection.

Answer (score 1):

## Custom script solution

If you need custom implementation, I would suggest to use Azure CLI for developing a custom script, and then run it in your Ansible playbook.

E.g. reference `fileshare.ps1` script with content of `az storage share create --account-name MyAccount --name MyFileShare` ...etc.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/share?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_share_create

## Simple solution with Ansible module (Edit: not sufficient at the moment)

Edit: this solution only creates the storage account as of now, so it is not sufficient in most scenarios.

There is an Ansible module for this, already implemented, called `azure_rm_storageaccount` in the `azure` namespace. See the link in the bottom.

Make sure to use the `kind` property and specify `FileStorage` value. Example:

```yaml
- name: Create an account with kind of FileStorage
  azure_rm_storageaccount:
    resource_group: souser_resource_group
    name: souser_file_storage
    type: Premium_LRS
    kind: FileStorage
    tags:
      testing: testing
```

Documentation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_storageaccount_module.html

Comment: bradib0y plus one for trying to understand the question ! You are on the right track. I doubt this is the one I am looking for but I will test it out again tomorrow. Because I was unable to get it to work using azure_rm_storageaccount, I posted a question on azure_rm_resource as that allows me to create any type of resource in Azure. The one I am looking for is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Microsoft might eventually support Azure File Share as there is a request pending https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/pull/603/files  ; until then I will need to use azure_rm_resource

Comment: Confirmed. It only creates a storage account. Thanks for trying bradib0y !

Comment: @souser , I modified my answer. If you have any questions, please put them here